# Problem with updating Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, updates

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-53-generic
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda5
I: (UUID=35ea86ce-fbf6-4344-a6f5-19dc7c85efae)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
```

Comment: this is only an info.

Comment: I can't see any problem.